Max Probability
I have 10 dice. All are rolled together and we calculate the probability of a sum of 31:
allpos = Tuples[{Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6], Range[6]}];
select = Cases[allpos, a_ /; Total[a] == 31];
prob = Length[select]/Length[allpos]

Which gives:  1696805/30233088 ~ 5.61%
Now two questions:
1)
How can we select all possible distinct set of 10 numbers from the set?
For example:  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 6, 6, 6} and {6, 6, 6, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} are the same (and so are any other arrangements of the same set across any position.
I like to suppress those and just say:
Six 1s and One 4 and Three Sixes are just one SET of solution and so on....  Given that, how many SETS of solutions are there for this?
In other words: How many distinct set of variations give me a sum of 31 using 10 numbers in the range of 1->6?
2)
The range of all sums will be between 10 and 60.  Is there a fast way to get all probabilities for each in 1 shot (not going through my method above) and sort them descending?

You may benefit from the books by David J. Blower. He was also a Mathematica enthusiast. The PDFs can be downloaded from my website: https://www.bayesinaction.nl.

Thx! got 4-5 of these now...!

Update 2: based on comment
Find combination was highest probability for range 10 to 60 for 10 independent dice rolls:
in[n_] := Module[{s, res},
  s = Select[Max[#] < 7 &][IntegerPartitions[n, {10}]];
  res = SortBy[{#, Length[Permutations[#]]} & /@ s, -#[[2]] &];
  {n, res[[1, 1]], res[[1, 2]]/6^10}]


all = Grid[in /@ Range[10, 60], Frame -> All]


Updated Answer
To find the partition with highest probability:
ip = Select[Max[#] < 7 &][IntegerPartitions[31, {10}]];
res = SortBy[{#, Length[Permutations[#]]} & /@ ip, -#[[2]] &];
grd = Grid[
  With[{tot = Total[res[[All, 2]]]}, {Row[#1, ","], #2/6^10} & @@@ 
    res], Frame -> All]


Original Answer
You can use IntegerPartitions, e.g.:
ip = Select[Max[#] < 7 &][IntegerPartitions[31, {10}]];
Total[(Length /@ Permutations /@ ip)]/6^10

->
1696805/30233088
Also, you can use MultinomialDistribution and TransformedDistribution to calculate  probability:
xa = Array[x, 6];
td = TransformedDistribution[Range[6] . xa, 
   xa \[Distributed] MultinomialDistribution[10, Table[1/6, 6]]];
Probability[z == 31, z \[Distributed] td]

-> 1696805/30233088
Grid[ip, Background -> {Automatic, {{LightBlue, White}}}]



Very fast!  The second part of the OP's question can be found by removing Total from Total[(Length /@ Permutations /@ ip)]/6^10.

@JimB I missed the second part so thanks for clarifying

Ooops!  I see the OP wants the probabilities associated with every unique set rather than just the sets that sum to 31.  Or just the individual sums.  I need to learn how to read.

The highest prob is 175/46656 using the first comment above from @JimB   However these do not show which numbers had the highest Prob

@Steve237 sorry I missed the point of the question but as JimB points out you can determine from the approach. I’ll edit answer when I get time.

Thx! No rush at all...

As a temporary band-aid try Transpose[{ip, (Length /@ Permutations /@ ip)/6^10}].  That's only dealing with the arrangements that sum to 31.

Amazing answers!!! Thanks so much JimB and @ubpdqn !!  I learn so much from these solutions almost weekly!  I am assuming the probability sorts in the table is against the DISTINCT answers only and if we re-arrange those it still stays same Prob.

Hi @ubpdqn  the probability sorts you gave all add up to 31. This is not what I was after exactly. I want to see the probabilities for all sets (which add up to between 10 and 60) and then sort them! Not just 31.... let me know...Thx

@Steve237 You can just apply same approach to the range you want. I’ll leave that to you. Good luck.
